# Gerrit how to squash commits on the remote?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have 9 push on the remote branch. They haven't been merged by admin. How do I squash them on one commit. They have merge conflict also.

Answer (score 1):

You do it locally and then force-push.

```
git checkout some-remote/some-branch
git reset --soft HEAD~9 # go back 9 revisions, I guess you meant
git commit -m "This is whatever fix" # I personally don't like squashes so I reset --soft/commit
git push -f some-remote HEAD:some-branch # replace remote branch
```

Comment: I'll try it now.

Comment: I created a new branch from local master. I pushed it to refs/for/master. what's the remote branch do I have to checkout?

Comment: the branch you need to checkout is the one you are referring to when you said _I have 9 push on the remote branch_.

Comment: I guess you could select it as **'the answer'**